# Get Longest Name

Tags: vb.net, linq, directoryinfo

I need the directory with the longest name. In the RootDir there may be several directories with names starting with "8000". I want the DirectoryInfo of the one with the longest name.

```
    Dim pCustID As String = "8000"
    Dim RootDir As New DirectoryInfo(CustPdfPath)
    Dim dirs() As DirectoryInfo
    dirs = Array.FindAll(RootDir.GetDirectories, Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith(pCustID))
    Dim myDir As DirectoryInfo = Array.Sort(RootDir.GetDirectories, _
                Function(x As DirectoryInfo, y As DirectoryInfo) _
                x.Name.Length > y.Name.Length).firstordefault
```

Of course I'm getting: "Expressions does not produce a value". How do I fix the last line to sort by length (longest first) and take the first (longest) one.

Comment: Let me clarify and you tell me if I am correct... You want to get the longest directory name given a starting path that starts with 8000? What about all sub directories?

Comment: That's right. Just ignore subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this (without using a DirectoryInfo)

```
Dim pCustID As String = "8000"
Dim RootDir As String = CustPdfPath
Dim longest = Directory.GetDirectories(RootDir) _
              .Where(Function(x) x.StartsWith(RootDir & "\" & pCustID)) _ 
              .OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Length) _ 
              .FirstOrDefault()
```

or with a DirectoryInfo

```
Dim pCustID As String = "8000"
Dim RootDir As New DirectoryInfo(CustPdfPath)    
Dim longest = di.GetDirectories() _ 
                .Where(Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith(pCustID)) _ 
                .OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Name.Length) _ 
                .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: The second one with DirectoryInfo works fine. Thanks. The first one returns nothing which is wrong. It should be returning the path or DirectoryInfo not sure which.

Comment: Ok fixed the first one. No need to GetFileName indeed

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the cause of my error. Array.Sort doesn't return anything just like the error message said. Instead it just sorts the array in place. Then I can just get the last one.

```
    Dim RootDir As New DirectoryInfo(CustPdfPath)
    Dim dirs() As DirectoryInfo
    dirs = Array.FindAll(RootDir.GetDirectories, Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith(CustPath))
    Array.Sort(RootDir.GetDirectories, _
                Function(x As DirectoryInfo, y As DirectoryInfo) x.Name.Length < y.Name.Length)
    Dim myDir As DirectoryInfo = dirs.LastOrDefault
```